# Jackson: Deserialize to a Map<String, Object> with correct type for each value

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a class that looks like the following

```
public class MyClass {
   private String val1;
   private String val2;
   private Map<String,Object> context;
   // Appropriate accessors removed for brevity.
   ...
}
```

I'm looking to be able to make the round trip with Jackson from object to JSON and back.  I can serialize the object above fine and receive the following output:

```
{
    "val1": "foo",
    "val2": "bar",
    "context": {
        "key1": "enumValue1",
        "key2": "stringValue1",
        "key3": 3.0
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that since the values in the serialized map do not have any type information, they are not deserialized correctly.  For example, in the sample above, enumValue1 should be deserialized as an enum value but is instead deserialized as a String.  I've seen examples for basing what type on a variety of things, but in my scenario, I won't know what the types are (they will be user generated objects that I won't know in advance) so I need to be able to serialize the type information with the key value pair.  How can I accomplish this with Jackson?

For the record, I'm using Jackson version 2.4.2.  The code I'm using to test the round trip is as follows:

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void testJsonSerialization() throws Exception {
    // Get test object to serialize
    T serializationValue = getSerializationValue();
    // Serialize test object
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(serializationValue);
    // Test that object was serialized as expected
    assertJson(json);
    // Deserialize to complete round trip
    T roundTrip = (T) mapper.readValue(json, serializationValue.getClass());
    // Validate that the deserialized object matches the original one
    assertObject(roundTrip);
}
```

Since this is a Spring based project, the mapper is being created as follows:

```
@Configuration
public static class SerializationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper mapper() {
        Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> mixins = new HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>();
        // Add unrelated MixIns
        .. 

        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .dateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormatWithMilliSeconds())
                .mixIns(mixins)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, of course that an `Object` won't have any type information; there's no way around that other than 1. create a POJO for your `context` instance variable (preferred); or 2. don't use a `Map<String, Object>` but an `ObjectNode`. In any event, this is a primary example of a code smell.

Comment: The `context` variable is being used in a fashion similar to `HttpSession` (It represents Spring Batch's `ExecutionContext` to be exact) so I wouldn't consider it a smell...it's what a `Map` is for.  What I don't understand is why Jackson can't add a field that indicates the type.  If it has the value, it has the class, and therefore can determine the type.  What am I missing?

Comment: And where would it add this field? You only tell it to deserialize that to an `Object`. The advantage with an `ObjectNode`, at least, is that you get the JSON directly; you can therefore query the type of the field with all that `JsonNode` has to help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the simplest way of achieve what you want is using:

```
ObjectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
```

This will add type information in the serialized json.

Here you are a running example, that you will need to adapt to Spring:

```
public class Main {

    public enum MyEnum {
        enumValue1
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.setContext(new HashMap<String, Object>());

        obj.setVal1("foo");
        obj.setVal2("var");
        obj.getContext().put("key1", "stringValue1");
        obj.getContext().put("key2", MyEnum.enumValue1);
        obj.getContext().put("key3", 3.0);

        mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);

        System.out.println(json);

        MyClass readValue = mapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);
        //Check the enum value was correctly deserialized
        Assert.assertEquals(readValue.getContext().get("key2"), MyEnum.enumValue1);
    }

}
```

The object will be serialized into something similar to:

```
[ "so_27871226.MyClass", {
  "val1" : "foo",
  "val2" : "var",
  "context" : [ "java.util.HashMap", {
    "key3" : 3.0,
    "key2" : [ "so_27871226.Main$MyEnum", "enumValue1" ],
    "key1" : "stringValue1"
  } ]
} ]
```

And will be deserialized back correctly, and the assertion will pass.

Bytheway there are more ways of doing this, please look at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization for more info.

I hope it will help.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for.  One small question.  This is at a global level.  Is there a way to specify this at a field level (There's only the one field I have this issue with so it would be nice to not litter the JSON with types everywhere).  Not a big deal, but can't hurt to ask.

Comment: I believe that enabling this option might affect unexpectedly the JSON produced by your object serialization. So I would not support enabling a global option for this case. 
What I would expect is that when I add a polymorphic instance into a Map/Collection the type serialization options are not ignored. Surprisingly though, when the polymorphic object exists under a container/aggregation object, the serialization options apply as expected.

Comment: I created a unit test that supports my statement: https://gist.github.com/sermojohn/9e16e240aee733d9ad8318443576a696

Comment: so... no problem, is it? note that I pointed that there are other ways of solving this question. I think your solution is described in docs as "1.2. Per-class annotations".

Comment: Also note that around 1/3 of all published security vulnerabilities in Jackson so far have been related to default typing. Maybe they've all been found and fixed, but maybe there are some left. If you're dealing with untrusted input (e.g. you get json data sent from users' web browsers), I would recommend finding some other solution.