# Returning Map<T, List<V>> as a JSON from Spring. Map key elements do not parse into JSON format

Tags: json, spring, dictionary, jackson

I have a question connected to returning `Map<T, List<V>>` as a JSON response.

I have a spring server which returns JSON objects, but now I'm exploring problem with returning `Map` in this format. I want return a `Map<T, List<V>>` from my server as a JSON and display it in the form like this:

```
-T.name:
    {
       V.somefield1 = ...,
       V.somefield2 = ...,
       .
       .
    },
    {
       V.somefield1 = ...,
       V.somefield2 = ...,
       .
       .
    },
-T.name:
    {
      ...
    }
 ....
```

I have a `@OneToMany` relation between objects `T` and `V`. Everything return in a good way, apart from `T` objects - Jackson return object `T` not as a JSON, but as a full package/path to `T` class in my project, like `[app.something.TObject.class]`. 
I cannot access to any field there.

Should I try to cast this object to `JSONObject` for example before I'll send it (I think it is stupid)? I have no idea why jackson parse objects in the list and return them in JSON format and do not change key objects `T` into JSON.

Any ideas or solutions how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Maybe look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871226/serialize-deserialize-mapstring-object-with-jackson) first.

---

Well, I had the same problem today and what I did was just creating a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object):

```
public class class MyDTO {
  public T key;
  public List<V> values;
}
```

and just convert it like that:

```
@GET // etc.
public List<MyDTO> getMyMap() {
  List<MyDTO> myDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
  for(T key : myMap.keys()) {
    MyDTO myDto = new MyDTO();
    myDto.key = key;
    myDto.values = myMap.get(key);
  }
  return myDtoList;
}
```

<del>I don't know if there is a better way. I'd be glad to know myself if there was.</del> It appears that [there is a way to do that a little different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871226/serialize-deserialize-mapstring-object-with-jackson).

Comment: It is ok when you return only a List<V>. I have many mapping methods which return only List<V> and everything is good. My problem is when I want return a Map<T, List<V>>. List<V> returns in JSON, but T elements not. Of course all my objects are DTOs, but it is not a case to this problem.

Comment: @allocer I know, I had the same issue - but wrapping it into another class did the trick for me. You could try it like this [but look at that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871226/serialize-deserialize-mapstring-object-with-jackson), maybe that is what you want.

Comment: Oh, ok, now I see. It looks like good, I will try it and give an answer soon.

Comment: It was a solution. I have done something like @Stefan Falk and everything works. Thanks ;).