# Serialize/Deserialize maps with different types with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize different types of maps differently. I want

```
Map<String, MyInterface> map1;
```

to be serialized and deserialized differently than

```
Map<String, String> map2;
```

I have created two serializers

```
public class MyFirstSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Property>> {
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class MySecondSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, String>> {
    ...
}
```

and two deserializers

```
public class MyFirstDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Property>> {
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class MySecondDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<String, String>> {
    ...
}
```

I then add them to my `Module` and specify the types:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, "beta"));
module.addSerializer(new MyFirstSerializer());
module.addDeserializer((Class<Map<String, Property>>) (Class<?>) Map.class, new MyFirstDeserializer());

module.addSerializer(new MySecondSerializer());
module.addDeserializer((Class<Map<String, String>>) (Class<?>) Map.class, new MySecondDeserializer());
```

The problem is, that maps of type  is sometimes passed to `MyFirstSerializer` or maps of type  is sometimes passed to `MySecondSerializer`.

I think the issue is that the types of the maps are erased at run time and there is no way to distinguish between the two different maps. How do I get around this?

I have looked at [Serialize/Deserialize Map<String, Object> with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871226/serialize-deserialize-mapstring-object-with-jackson) but could not find a solution.

Comment: Maybe defining your own types so they don't get erased, like `public class MyInterfaceMap extends Map<String, MyInterface> { ... }` and then creating your (de)serializers based on your types `public class MyFirstSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyInterfaceMap> { ... }`, might work.

Comment: @walen this is the solution that I also arrived at. If there are no other solutions I will end up doing this, so feel free to add an answer

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use [`jackson.core.type.TypeReference`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) for this kind of job:

```java
Map<String, Property> parsed = 
    objectMapper.readValue(
        jsonString, 
        new TypeReference<Map<String, Property>>() {}
    );
```

`TypeReference` is able to store generic type argument at runtime which allows jackson to infer value type and deserialize it correctly w/o any need in custom (de)serializers.

The other way is desrialize json using explicitly defined [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/CollectionType.html):

```
CollectionType collectionType =
    objectMapper.getTypeFactory()
        .constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, Property.class);
List<Map<String, Property>> objects = 
    mapper.readValue(jsonString, collectionType);
```