# Extract values from map(it's field) and write it into JSON

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

Using `ObjectMapper` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`is it possible to extract values from map and write it into JSON ? Without extra tag for map ?

For example we have class:

```
public class LoginInfoJSON {
    private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    private String username;
    private String password;

    //getters and setters + constructor
}
```

If we try to convert it into JSON it will be:

```
{
  "properties":
     {
      "numberTest":22,
      "array":["John","Anna","Peter"],
      "nullTest":null,
      "booleanTest":true,
      "employee":{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"},
      "stringTest":"String"
      },
   "username":"pwe",
   "password":"pwe"
}
```

But is it possible to make it like that?

```
{
    "numberTest":22,
    "array":["John","Anna","Peter"],
    "nullTest":null,
    "booleanTest":true,
    "employee":{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"},
    "stringTest":"String",
    "username":"pwe",
    "password":"pwe"
}
```

May be some annotation can handle it ?

Could someone please suggest something ?

**EDIT**

As was suggested - I should write my own serializer,

but I am facing with problem right now:
So here is my serizlizer:

```
public class ItemSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String,Object> map, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        Annotation[] mapAnnotations = map.getClass().getAnnotations();
        for(int i = 0; i < mapAnnotations.length; i++){
            if(mapAnnotations[i].getClass().isInstance(MapPropertiesAnnotation.class)){
                jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
                for(Map.Entry<String, Object> mapEntry : map.entrySet()){
                    jsonGenerator.writeObjectField(mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue());
                }
                jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I am adding this as module to `ObjectMapper`:

```
public class MapModule extends SimpleModule {
    public MapModule() {
        addSerializer(Map.class, new ItemSerializer());
    }
}
```

And here during the maven build I am facing with error:

```
error: method addSerializer in class SimpleModule cannot be applied to given types;
```

so, I think that the problem is that I am trying to serialize `(Map<String, Object>)` not just `Map`.

How should I declare then my map to serialize ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize/Deserialize Map<String, Object> with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871226/serialize-deserialize-mapstring-object-with-jackson)

Comment: @Catalin that is not what OP wants

Comment: I think what you want is against the JSON representation of objects. If you receive such a JSON, then you would need some custom parser, because you can't tell directly which objects come from the map and which not

Comment: @XtremeBaumer ok, thanks for the answer

Comment: You can write a custom serializer for this

Comment: @user7 yea, I am already doing this, thank you