# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Tags: java, serialization, objectmapper

I am writing a custom serialization using Jackson library.

And during the serialization I am facing with error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

So here is my serialization (I can't even go inside this method during the debug it crashes when I call `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(loginInfoJSON);`):

```
public class ItemSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String,Object> map, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        Annotation[] mapAnnotations = map.getClass().getAnnotations();
        for(int i = 0; i < mapAnnotations.length; i++){
            if(mapAnnotations[i].getClass().isInstance(MapPropertiesAnnotation.class)){
                jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
                for(Map.Entry<String, Object> mapEntry : map.entrySet()){
                    jsonGenerator.writeObjectField(mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue());
                }
                jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I am creating a module for this to add it to the ObjectMapper:
Hard cast to avoid problem during the maven build.

```
public class MapModule extends SimpleModule {
    public MapModule() {
        addSerializer((Class<Map<String,Object>>)(Class)Map.class, new ItemSerializer());
    }
}
```

I am also add extra annotaion for my map:

```
@JsonSerialize(keyUsing = ItemSerializer.class)
private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
```

Could anyone please suggest why is this happening ?

**EDIT**

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String JSONValue =  objectMapper.writeValueAsString(loginInfoJSON);
            System.out.println(JSONValue);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: where is the `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(loginInfoJSON);` call?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I've edit the info.

Comment: I still can't see the flow of the program. Maybe you can explain the flow

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have a task right now, it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362720/extract-values-from-mapits-field-and-write-it-into-json this topic, and I am need to serialize map, you already seen this topic. So and now I am facing with this problem

Comment: From what I see, I would say that you are missing to register the `module` on the `ObjectMapper`. Something like `objectMapper.registerModule(new MapModule());`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It's actually exists, I didn't add this to topic. 'mapper.registerModule(new MapModule());'

Comment: Always include the whole code... At which line exactly is the error thrown?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer here 'String JSONValue =  objectMapper.writeValueAsString(loginInfoJSON);'

Comment: Did you try debugging? I would guess that somewhere in the `ItemSerializer` the error actually occurs. Of what type is `loginInfoJSON`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer unfortunatelly I can't evet go through serialize method - In debug mode I am able to debug only this line : public class ItemSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Object>> { then it crashes

Comment: Of what type is `loginInfoJSON`?